# Sending Voice over UDP with Java Sound API

Tags: java, audio, udp, voip, javasound

I developed a Java application using Java Sound API. What it does is it captures data coming from the microphone and sends it over UDP to other computer for it to be played there. Now, I am having sound volume, quality and speed issues. I can't figure out source of the problems so I need help in figuring out what's wrong with the program.

---

### Update

It seems that speed issues are due to Java Sound API just being slow. I tried the program without UDP sockets and there was same kind of delay so UDP doesn't introduce extra delay in LAN. Echo problem goes away when the program is used with earphones. Quality of the sound isn't too bad overall. Only remaining problem is volume.

Below is the **sender:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class VoipApp
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 44100.0f;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        int channels = 2;
        int frameSize = 4;
        boolean bigEndian = true;

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8)
                * channels, rate, bigEndian);

        TargetDataLine line;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)){
            System.out.println("Not Supported");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8081);
        //InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.14");

        try
        {
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);

            //ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int numBytesRead;
            byte[] data = new byte [line.getBufferSize() / 5];
            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            line.start();
            while(true){
                numBytesRead = line.read(data,0, data.length);
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, IPAddress, 8080);
               // totalBytesRead += numBytesRead;
                socket.send(sendPacket);
               //out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
               // System.out.println("Debug");
            }

        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the **receiver:**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class VoipAppTwo
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        AudioFormat.Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
        float rate = 44100.0f;
        int sampleSize = 16;
        int channels = 2;
        int frameSize = 4;
        boolean bigEndian = true;

        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(encoding, rate, sampleSize, channels, (sampleSize / 8)
                * channels, rate, bigEndian);

        SourceDataLine speakers;
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        speakers.open(format);

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(8080);
        byte[] data = new byte[speakers.getBufferSize() / 5];
        speakers.start();
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            socket.receive(receivePacket);
            speakers.write(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts, with caveat that I don't have direct experience with trying to use UDP.

It seems to me that missing and out-of-order packets (assumed with UDP) would have to be "dealt with" or else the expected discontinuities would continually create disruptively loud clicks. But IDK how this is normally done. Filters? Buffering? Encapsulation of the packet data into windowing (Hann or Hamming?) frames to bridge packet discontinuities?

javax.sound.sampled is quite close to the native sound. [Here is a good article to reference on considerations pertaining to real time, low latency Java-based audio.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/i/icmc/bbp2372.2007.131/1)

Comment: I managed to make it almost real-time with ALSA Sound API.

Comment: Nice to hear a solution has been found! How do you access the ALSA API? Are you doing it through Java, e.g., selecting ALSA lines? (Still using TargetDataLine/SourceDataLine?) Or some other way?

Comment: Do consider writing up your solution and marking it as the answer. It would be a valuable contribution.

Comment: I am using C in Linux(ALSA API is only available in Linux). The delay between audio capture and playback is almost none compared to Java Sound API but there is noise in the background - which I couldn't get rid of. Once I fix the noise problem, I can post the solution here. But it is not ready yet.

Comment: I also tried using  Pulseaudio for capture and playback. It is far easier to use than using ALSA API but there is same kind of delay between capture and playback just like it is with Java Sound API.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I am able to answer my own question here. I used **ALSA API**(Linux), **PulseAudio**(Linux) and **JackAudio**(Linux) to make the program almost real-time(less than 1 sec delay). PulseAudio's blocking API was much nicer to use than both ALSA and JackAudio but I experienced same kind of delay that I had experienced with Java Sound API. JackAudio is a low-latency audio server for professional audio work. I saw this example : https://github.com/jackaudio/example-clients/blob/master/simple_client.c and soon realized that it was for mono output.
I modified the code a bit to make it stereo, then added UDP sockets and a second callback function. Callback functions work as if they are separate threads so there was no need to introduce POSIX threads.

The code isn't perfect, probably not a good way to use JackAudio and has tons of bugs in it. However, I believe it is a good starting point for those who are interested in these kind of stuff. To use it, first install `JackAudio` server and development files through your distribution's package manager.

Let me know if there is a better way to implement the same functionality with whatever set of tools available out there.

### JackAudio

**JackAudio Solution:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <jack/jack.h>

#define PORT 8080

int create_UDP_socket_send(struct sockaddr_in * server, const char * ip)
{
    int sock;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(server, 0, sizeof(*server));
    server->sin_family = AF_INET;
    server->sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    return sock;
}

int create_UDP_socket_receive()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int sock;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return sock;
}

typedef struct{
    int socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
} __Info__;

jack_port_t *input_port;
jack_port_t *output_port1;
jack_port_t *output_port2;
jack_client_t *client1;
jack_client_t *client2;

int processFirst (jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    jack_default_audio_sample_t *in, *out;

    __Info__ * info = (__Info__ *) arg;
    
    in = jack_port_get_buffer (input_port, nframes);
    sendto(info->socket, in, sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t) * nframes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&(info->server), sizeof(info->server));

    return 0;
}

int processSecond (jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{
    jack_default_audio_sample_t *out1, *out2;
    
    int * socket = (int *)arg;

    out1 = jack_port_get_buffer (output_port1, nframes);
    out2 = jack_port_get_buffer (output_port2, nframes);
    unsigned char buffer[sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t) * nframes];
    recvfrom(*socket, buffer, sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t) * nframes, 0, NULL, NULL);
    memcpy(out1, buffer, sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t) * nframes);
    memcpy(out2, buffer, sizeof(jack_default_audio_sample_t) * nframes);

    return 0;
}

void jack_shutdown (void *arg)
{
    exit (1);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char **ports;
    const char *client_name1 = "simple1";
    const char *client_name2 = "simple2";
    const char *server_name = NULL;
    jack_options_t options = JackNullOption;
    jack_status_t status;

    client1 = jack_client_open (client_name1, options, &status, server_name);
    if (client1 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "jack_client_open() failed, "
             "status = 0x%2.0x\n", status);
        if (status & JackServerFailed) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Unable to connect to JACK server\n");
        }
        exit (1);
    }

    client2 = jack_client_open (client_name2, options, &status, server_name);
    if (client2 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "jack_client_open() failed, "
             "status = 0x%2.0x\n", status);
        if (status & JackServerFailed) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Unable to connect to JACK server\n");
        }
        exit (1);
    }

    if (status & JackServerStarted) {
        fprintf (stderr, "JACK server started\n");
    }

    if (status & JackNameNotUnique) {
        client_name1 = jack_get_client_name(client1);
        fprintf (stderr, "unique name `%s' assigned\n", client_name1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int socket = create_UDP_socket_send(&server, argv[1]);
    __Info__ info = {
        socket, 
        server
    };

    int socket2 = create_UDP_socket_receive();

    jack_set_process_callback (client1, processFirst, &info);
    jack_set_process_callback (client2, processSecond, &socket2);

    jack_on_shutdown (client1, jack_shutdown, 0);
    jack_on_shutdown (client2, jack_shutdown, 0);

    printf ("engine sample rate: %" PRIu32 "\n", jack_get_sample_rate (client1));
    printf ("engine sample rate: %" PRIu32 "\n", jack_get_sample_rate (client2));

    input_port = jack_port_register (client1, "input", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE, JackPortIsInput, 0);
    output_port1 = jack_port_register (client2, "output1", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 0);
    output_port2 = jack_port_register (client2, "output2", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 1);

    if ((input_port == NULL) || (output_port1 == NULL) || (output_port2 == NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no more JACK ports available\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (jack_activate (client1)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot activate client");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (jack_activate (client2)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot activate client2");
        exit (1);
    }

    ports = jack_get_ports (client1, NULL, NULL, JackPortIsPhysical | JackPortIsOutput);
    if (ports == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no physical capture ports\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (jack_connect (client1, ports[0], jack_port_name (input_port))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot connect input ports\n");
    }

    free (ports);
    
    ports = jack_get_ports (client2, NULL, NULL, JackPortIsPhysical | JackPortIsInput);
    if (ports == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no physical playback ports\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (jack_connect (client2, jack_port_name (output_port1), ports[0])) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot connect output ports\n");
    }

    if (jack_connect (client2, jack_port_name (output_port2), ports[1])) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot connect output ports\n");
    }

    sleep (-1);

    jack_client_close (client1);
    jack_client_close (client2);
    exit (0);
}
```

### ALSA API

I used the code from the following tutorial: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735?page=0,2 Occasionally, there happens to be underruns at the receiver side.

**ALSA API Sender:**

```
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define PORT 8080

int create_UDP_socket_send(struct sockaddr_in * server, const char * address)
{
  int sock;
  if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
  {
    perror("Socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(server, 0, sizeof(*server));
  server->sin_family = AF_INET;
  server->sin_port = htons(PORT);
  server->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((const char *)address);

  return sock;
}

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  //char *buffer;

  /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open pcm device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
  val = 44100;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 32;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
  
  size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
  // buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
  char buffer[size];

  int nsent;
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  int socket = create_UDP_socket_send(&server, "127.0.0.1");

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &val, &dir);

  while (1) {
    rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
    if (rc == -EPIPE) {
      /* EPIPE means overrun */
      fprintf(stderr, "overrun occurred\n");
      snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
    } else if (rc < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error from read: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
    } else if (rc != (int)frames) {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, read %d frames\n", rc);
    }
    // rc = write(1, buffer, size);
    if((nsent = sendto(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))) < 0)
    {
      perror("sendto()");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);

  return 0;
}
```

**ALSA API Receiver:**

```
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define PORT 8080

int create_UDP_socket_receive()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int sock;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return sock;
}

int main() {
    long loops;
    int rc;
    int size;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    unsigned int val;
    int dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;

  /* Open PCM device for playback. */
    rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open pcm device: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, 2);

  /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
    val = 44100;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &val, &dir);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
    frames = 32;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
    rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
    
    size = frames * 4; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
    char buffer[size];

    int nread;
    int socket = create_UDP_socket_receive();

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &val, &dir);

    while (1) {

        if((nread = recvfrom(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // write(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        rc = snd_pcm_writei(handle, buffer, frames);
        if (rc == -EPIPE) {
        /* EPIPE means underrun */
            fprintf(stderr, "underrun occurred\n");
            snd_pcm_prepare(handle);
        } else if (rc < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error from writei: %s\n", snd_strerror(rc));
        }  else if (rc != (int)frames) {
            fprintf(stderr, "short write, write %d frames\n", rc);
        }
    }

    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Voice over network are a complex subject and have a lot of tricky problem.

I think your problem come from the irregularity of your network layer.

If your network is not 100% constante (it's very difficult with the interference of other application in the buffer of your computer/box/etc..)  your voice will be a little robotics.

One way for avoiding this is to add a little buffer who will delay the communication between receiver and sender. If the delay is too low the performance problem effect will continue to happend. If it's too long well it's too long ;)...

Another problem who can occurs (most likely in WAN Network ) is the lost of packet who can trouble the communication. For resolve this issue.. I don't have good solution it's depends of the network or/and the use case.

Comment: So, I got rid of UDP sockets and just used `TargetDataLine` and `SourceDataLine` on a buffer to see if the problem was caused by UDP sockets. It turns out that UDP sockets do not cause the delay, but rather it is the Java Sound API. I need a faster API| than those offered by Java. What is my alternatives? I can rewrite it in C++ too, but I haven't found any library in C++ to reach out the microphone and the speakers.

Comment: Maybe Beads or Jsyn for java library

Comment: Python is a possiblity... 
But i'm find strange that java is not faster enough for playing sound

Comment: I would say it is fast enough, but I need something close to real-time.

Comment: I've tried your code with 2 computer abd in fact it work well (I've a little echo but that's all)

Comment: There is a noticeable delay in between. I wanna make it almost real-time and get rid of the echo.

Comment: At that point you should define real time ( how many ms ? I agree the echo is troublesome )